# proxy_fcgi:error and timeout in server log--is a vulnerability being exploited on my server?

Tags: apache, security

My LAMP web server on AWS became briefly unresponsive this morning and looking at the log it looks like it was getting hammered with requests from a suspicious IP. My network activity monitor spiked and there were a bunch of these events in the log:

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 27335:tid 139984352806656] (70007)The timeout
>   specified has expired: [client 94.242.62.244:45600] AH01075: Error
>   dispatching request to : (polling), referer:
>   https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/trending/

This happened a couple days ago (different IP address), and I added this to my httpd.conf:

```
<Proxy "*"> 
Require ip 18.188.18.89 [that's my server's IP address]
</Proxy>
```

But apparently I need to do more here. If anybody can explain exactly what these malicious servers are trying to do and how I harden Apache against it I'd be most grateful. I blacklisted the IP but I that's not a total solution as it looks like new attacks from other IPs are coming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting server up for long time then, probably your server under attack by DDOS and as far as I know blacklisting certain IP's are not enough to over come this attack, best way to get things out is keep every thing in good DDOS protection shield and also make sure you application have proper clustering.

On AWS you can manage AWS shield as well to mitigate DDOS and similar attacks.